# How to extract only numbers from a list of tuples

Tags: python, django

```
poi = booking_models.TestBooking.objects.filter(customer_visit=instance).values_list("package__package_name", "amount").order_by("package").distinct()

[(None, 392.0), (None, 530.0), ('RahulNewPaackage', 3999.0), ('Suraj pkg today all', 699.0), ('suraj 44', 599.0)]
```

I am learning python and django and trying to get only numbers from this output(poi). I want to get this in a list like this **[392.0, 530.0, 3999.0, 699.0, 599.0]**. As poi will iterate many times so every time till the last item there will be output of list of numbers. How to achieve this ? Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You each time want the second item, so you can work with list comprehension:

```
[x for _, x in poi]
```